# How can I submit additional data when uploading a file with the jQuery Form Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using Malsup's jQuery Form Plugin to upload files asynchronously, [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/166221/355682).

It works great for uploading files, but I'm interested in sending additional data along with the file (such as the username of the person uploading it.

Is there some way to add this additional data?

Here's the current code that works for uploading files:

(Assume a standard `<input type=file/>` in an HTML form with `id=upload`)

```
// site/js/app.js

var app = app || {};

(function($){


})(jQuery);

// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 



         var options =
         { 
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/file_upload',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response, statusText, xhr, form) 
            {
                alert('success!');
            }; 

        $("#upload").ajaxForm(options);

});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After playing around with it for a few days, I found the answer.

Simply put, there is an 'options' property of "data" which contains everything that will be sent to the server. When using the Form is set to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, this grabs only the file type inputs, ignoring everything else.

However, if you can access the values of the other input fields (sounds like a job for $!), you can manually add the extra data with a specific callback function.

This would make your jQuery code look like this:

```
// site/js/app.js

var app = app || {};

(function($){


})(jQuery);

/*
$('#upload').submit(function()
{

    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;

})*/

// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 



         var options =
         { 
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/file_upload',
            dataType: 'json',

            beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) 
            {
                //add additional data that is going to be submit
                //for example
                arr.push({ 'name': 'username',
                           'value': 'Jarrod Dixon'});
            }, 


        }; 

        $("#upload").ajaxForm(options);

});
```

In my case, I'm using express.js as my webserver, which means the additional data is available in app.post's response's 'param' property as `req.param('username')`.

i.e.,

```
app.post('/file_upload', function(req, res) {

    //see if we got the username
    console.log('name = '+ req.param('username'));
    //Jarrod Dixon
});
```

Hope this helps save someone else fruitless hours of searching!